# Можно ли оптимизировать представленные свойства?

Tags: c#, .net, оптимизация

У объекта есть 3 свойства, представляющие разные типы треков, видео, аудио, и субтитры.

Неуправляемый код отдает эти треки использую `union`, а дальше происходит разделение на разные типы. Неуправляемая структура в представлении `ｃ＃`

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal unsafe struct MediaTrack
{
    internal uint Codec;
    internal uint OriginalFcc;
    internal int Id;
    internal TrackType Type;

    internal int Profile;
    internal int Level;

    internal _ Track;

    internal uint Bitrate;
    internal byte* _language;
    internal byte* _description;

    internal string Language
    {
        get
        {
            if (_language == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            byte* tmpPtr = _language;
            int size = 0;
            while (*tmpPtr != 0)
            {
                tmpPtr++;
                size++;
            }

            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_language, size);
        }
    }

    internal string Description
    {
        get
        {
            if (_description == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            byte* tmpPtr = _description;
            int size = 0;
            while (*tmpPtr != 0)
            {
                tmpPtr++;
                size++;
            }

            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_description, size);
        }
    }

    internal IVideoTrack ToVideoTrack()
    {
        if (Type != TrackType.Video)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return
            new VideoTrack(Codec, OriginalFcc, Id, Bitrate, Language, Description, Track.Video->Width,
            Track.Video->Height, Track.Video->SarNum, Track.Video->SarDen, Track.Video->FrameRateNum,
            Track.Video->FrameRateDen);
    }

    internal IAudioTrack ToAudioTrack()
    {
        if (Type != TrackType.Audio)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new AudioTrack(Codec, OriginalFcc, Id, Bitrate, Language, Description, Track.Audio->Channels, Track.Audio->Rate);
    }

    internal ISubtitleTrack ToSubtitleTrack()
    {
        if (Type != TrackType.Text)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new SubtitleTrack(Codec, OriginalFcc, Id, Bitrate, Language, Description, Track.Subtitle->Encoding);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct _
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal audio_* Audio;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal video_* Video;
        [FieldOffset(0)] internal subtitle_* Subtitle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct audio_
    {
        public uint Channels;
        public uint Rate;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct video_
    {
        internal uint Width;
        internal uint Height;
        internal uint SarNum;
        internal uint SarDen;
        internal uint FrameRateNum;
        internal uint FrameRateDen;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct subtitle_
    {
        private readonly byte* _encoding;

        internal string Encoding
        {
            get
            {
                byte* tmpPtr = _encoding;
                int size = 0;
                while (*tmpPtr != 0)
                {
                    tmpPtr++;
                    size++;
                }

                return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_encoding, size);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А свойства которые я думаю могли бы быть оптимизированы вот так:

```
public ICollection<IVideoTrack> VideoTracks
{
    get
    {
        unsafe
        {
            if (!IsParsed)
            {
                Parse();
            }

            MediaTrack** tracks = null;
            uint count = NativeMethods.Media.GetTracks(this, &tracks);
            if (count == 0 || tracks == null)
            {
                return Array.Empty<IVideoTrack>();
            }

            LinkedList<IVideoTrack> videoTracks = new LinkedList<IVideoTrack>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //TODO: please... do not edit next line... it is not possible to get NullReferenceException when we get any objects from C...
                IVideoTrack currentTrack = (*(tracks + i))->ToVideoTrack();
                if (currentTrack is null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                videoTracks.AddLast(currentTrack);
            }

            NativeMethods.Media.TracksRelease(tracks, count);
            return videoTracks;
        }
    }
}

public ICollection<IAudioTrack> AudioTracks
{
    get
    {
        unsafe
        {
            if (!IsParsed)
            {
                Parse();
            }

            MediaTrack** tracks = null;
            uint count = NativeMethods.Media.GetTracks(this, &tracks);
            if (count == 0 || tracks == null)
            {
                return Array.Empty<IAudioTrack>();
            }

            LinkedList<IAudioTrack> videoTracks = new LinkedList<IAudioTrack>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //TODO: please... do not edit next line... it is not possible to get NullReferenceException when we get any objects from C...
                IAudioTrack currentTrack = (*(tracks + i))->ToAudioTrack();
                if (currentTrack is null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                videoTracks.AddLast(currentTrack);
            }

            NativeMethods.Media.TracksRelease(tracks, count);
            return videoTracks;
        }
    }
}

public ICollection<ISubtitleTrack> SubtitleTracks
{
    get
    {
        unsafe
        {
            if (!IsParsed)
            {
                Parse();
            }

            MediaTrack** tracks = null;
            uint count = NativeMethods.Media.GetTracks(this, &tracks);
            if (count == 0 || tracks == null)
            {
                return Array.Empty<ISubtitleTrack>();
            }

            LinkedList<ISubtitleTrack> videoTracks = new LinkedList<ISubtitleTrack>();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //TODO: please... do not edit next line... it is not possible to get NullReferenceException when we get any objects from C...
                ISubtitleTrack currentTrack = (*(tracks + i))->ToSubtitleTrack();
                if (currentTrack is null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                videoTracks.AddLast(currentTrack);
            }

            NativeMethods.Media.TracksRelease(tracks, count);
            return videoTracks;
        }
    }
}
```

Думаю что можно уменшить кол-во вызовов　`GetTracks`, и `ReleaseTracks`, но мне ничего не приходит на ум...

Comment: А зачем их уменьшать? Они же в разных местах (свойствах) происходят. Метод `GetTracks` является тяжеловесным? Если все три свойства вызываются _всегда_ в процессе работы, то есть есть смысл внутри `GetTracks` закэшировать данные. То есть первый его вызов будет медленным, а остальные - быстрыми.

Comment: Ну смысла от кэширования нет, т.к. субтитры могу добавляться прямо в рантайме. Вызов не сильно тяжеловесный, однако, выделение памяти происходит при каждом вызове.

Comment: То есть `GetTracks` создаёт _копию_ данных? Переписываем код так, чтобы возвращался указатель (ссылка) на существующую коллекцию. Тогда и релизить нечего будет. PS: если так заботит память, то почему используется `LinkedList`, а не, скажем, `List`? Ведь связный список расточителен по памяти.

Comment: Я не могу это изменить, т.к. это неуправляемые функции. А насчет листа, даже не знаю, нельзя делать перечисление через индекс.